# Jquery Thickbox (Wordpress) - Dialog Window 2nd, 3rd, .. etc. won't close. 1st one will?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, thickbox

Do you know what could be the issue I'm having with Wordpress's version of Thickbox (Jquery)?

I've created within my framework a field that will load other fields via Wordpress's Thickbox.

Everything works fine in loading and showing it's respective fields, but the close button only works for the first rendered field using the Thickbox.

I've created a custom close button to be more user friendly and I thought maybe that was the issue, but it's not. I removed the custom button and kept the default close button and have the same problem.

All the value for opening the Thickbox are unique and I've looked over the code for this time and time again and couldn't find anything online about this.

Hopefully someone way more familiar with Jquery or this Thickbox help point me in the right direction? I'm lost with what might be the issue now.

Here is a 25 second screencast of the issue @ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vtkr5dVFZ_o

Thickbox Reference: 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Javascript_Reference/ThickBox

Reference Wordpress Thickbox JS Script: 
https://gist.github.com/NoahjChampion/1a28b473797a727098260c1efc92add9

Wordpress Javascript Reference: 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Javascript_Reference

Comment: Can you show the jquery/javascript code that control those buttons?

Comment: @Mauro - Thanks. Sorry, I meant to post the first reference link. I updated my question with that reference, another one and a gist of the actually Thickbox script. Hopefully you can take a look. I'm lost with it.